# Amchart bullet in certain point using external data loader

Tags: amcharts

I have external data(json) load to my amcharts serial/line chart. I generate the data using mySQL to json using PHP.

I want to display custom bullet using the dataLoader at certain point only(ie: if value == 200, show custom display). I already Google-ed the solution but mostly using the dataProvider which is ready-made in the chart script.

Please if anyone have the idea/solution/example please enlighten me.

Comment: The dataLoader simply loads JSON that looks like the dataProvider after the data loads. Assuming you're referring to [this demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/line-with-custom-bullets/) that uses the [customBulletField](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#customBulletField), simply include that URL as part of your output for points that are equal to 200. You'll need to tweak your PHP logic to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Now I get the idea and it works. Thanks a lot pal